# Multibinding as resource in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, multibinding

Is it possible (if yes how), to  add [multivaluebinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) expression into resource.

I have a Multivalue binding, that takes 2 separate binding, and converter parameter in one of those binding.

I have to use this binding to 5 Different items, and those binding tags differ only in converter parameter. Rest everything is same.

I would to avoid repetition of multibinding boilerplate tags.

Comment: All you need is a possibility to create xaml-functions. We'd love to have them, but they don't exist.
If you apply MVVM pattern, you'll be able to replace a multibinding with an additional property, that reflects some additional logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy way of seeing if something works: TRY IT!

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OmgLolzConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="One" Converter="{StaticResource CakeConverter}"/>
                    <Binding Path="Two" Converter="{StaticResource CakeConverter}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Works fine.