# Bind a property to an existing Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, properties, staticresource

I have an interface with multiple buttons. I'd like to enable or disable these buttons according to a 'complex' condition. I declared this MultiBinding as an application resource in order to avoid code repetition:

```
<MultiBinding x:Key="MyMultiBinding" Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyConverter}">
    <Binding Path="IsConnected" />
    <Binding Path="IsOpened" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Here is how I declare my button:

```
<Button Name="MyButton" Content="Click me!" IsEnabled="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyMultiBinding}" />
```

At runtime, I get the following error: "Set property IsEnabled threw an exception... MultiBinding is not a valid value for property IsEnabled".

I can't figure why this is not working. Could you please point me to the right way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if a `MultiBinding` is even allowed as a resource. I can't even get it to compile `A 'MultiBinding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'DictionaryEntry'. A 'MultiBinding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.` Simplest way seems to be to indeed wrap it into a `Style` and do your property Binding there and apply that `Style` to your control's either with a specific key or making it implicit. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14970686/1834662)

Comment: MultiBinding is allowed as a resource. I can add one in Application.Resources without any problem. Anyway, I wraped it into a Style and that's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the boolean `IsEnabled` property to a value of type `MultiBinding`. That is what is happening.

As @Viv pointed out, you could declare a `Style` to do the heavy lifting:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyConverter}">
                <Binding Path="IsConnected" />
                <Binding Path="IsOpened" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value> 
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Button Name="MyButton" Content="Click me!" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

This works well if the `Button` `DataContext` has those properties. It works especially well if they each have a different `DataContext` they are bound to, enabling them for different reasons.

If they are all bound to the same `DataContext`, or the properties are on a different object, you could use the [Freezable Trick](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) to provide a value that your buttons would bind to:

```
<BindingProxy x:Key="isEnabled">
    <BindingProxy.Data>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsConnected" />
            <Binding Path="IsOpened" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </BindingProxy.Data>
</BindingProxy>

<Button Name="MyButton" Content="Click me!" IsEnabled="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource isEnabled}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but wrapping the MultiBinding into a style, as Viv said, did the trick. Here is the code of the Style :

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="IsConnected" />
                    <Binding Path="IsDataAccessOpened" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

And the code of the button :

```
<Button Name="MyButton" Content="Click me!" Style={StaticResource ResourceKey=MyStyle} />
```