# How to access a MultiBinding defined in Application Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I´d like to reuse a MultiBinding and tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701391/multibinding-as-resource-in-xaml), but I can´t seem to reach IsEnabled from a Setter Property.

So I tried this approach, but no cigar :

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Test.MODEL"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>     
    <view:BooleanConverter x:Key="BooleanConverter" />
    <view:BooleanMultiConverter x:Key="BooleanMultiConverter" />
    <MultiBinding x:Key="OnOffBinding" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanMultiConverter}" ConverterParameter="OR">
            <Binding Path="model:CustomerIsDefined" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanConverter}" />
            <Binding Path="model:CustomerIsConfirmed" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanConverter}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainWindow.xaml > These two attempts will not compile :

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{StaticResource OnOffBinding}"/>
<TextBox IsEnabled="{MultiBinding {StaticResource OnOffBinding}}" />
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** After accepting Funcs answer I guess this has allready been answered in the linked thread. Sorry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it in Style

```
<Application.Resources>
    <view:BooleanConverter x:Key="BooleanConverter" />
    <view:BooleanMultiConverter x:Key="BooleanMultiConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="ControlEnabler" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding x:Key="OnOffBinding" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanMultiConverter}" ConverterParameter="OR">
                    <Binding Path="model:CustomerIsDefined" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanConverter}" />
                    <Binding Path="model:CustomerIsConfirmed" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanConverter}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ControlEnabler}"/>
```

Note `TargetType="Control"` making it generic.

Comment: Style="{StaticResource ControlEnabler}" will give you a cast not valid. As I wrote I allready tried this approach and if you try to do this on the local level you will discover that you can´t reach IsEnabled from a Setters Property

Comment: @noontz It works, tried it. your MultiBinding would need to return a boolean.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Could you show me the code for your BooleanMultiConverter? I return a boolean, but I can´t even compile your app.xaml snippet : Error MC3032 on the x:Key="OnOffBinding" part

Comment: It works here as well.. Donno what was wrong before, but now I have what I wan´t, and seemingly my question is redundant..  Thanks.